# error 'nzchar()' requires a character vector lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

i am trying to run code from the webpage https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/AppliedPredictiveModeling/inst/chapters/CreateGrantData.R?view=markup&revision=11&root=apm.

i get an error when i run below line

```
month info startTime <- dmy(raw$Start.date)
```

Error in parse_date_time(dates, orders, quiet = quiet, tz = tz, locale = locale,  :
  'nzchar()' requires a character vector

Code from above webpage needs some tweaks. One has to copy file "unimelb_training.csv" on his computer. The file is available at http://www.kaggle.com/c/unimelb/data

i have already contacted the author. He wasnt able to reproduce the error and therefore couldnt help. He suggested me to provide link of the above webpage instead of copy-pasting the entire code.The book site is http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/

Please help...thanks

Answer (score 5):

i emailed author of the lubridate package. his name and response as below:

Garrett Grolemund

Your error comes from a bug in lubridate that we are working on. The parsing functions can't handle factors at the moment. `raw$Start.date` is a factor. You can make your code work by putting `as.character()` around `raw$Start.date`, e.g.

```
startTime <- dmy(as.character(raw$Start.date))
```

I'll have this fixed in the next release of lubridate.

Cheers,
Garrett